# Running kubectl commands in parallel with different credentials

Tags: kubernetes, parallel-processing, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I'm currently running two Kubernetes clusters one on Google cloud and one on IBM cloud. To manage them I use kubectl. I've made a script that executes some commands on one of the clusters then switches to the other and does some other work there.
This works fine as long as the script only runs in one process, however when run in parallel the credentials are sometimes overwritten by one process when in use by another and this obviously causes issues.

I therefore want to know if I can supply kubectl with a credentials file for every call, instead of storing it in a environmental variable with `kubectl config set-credentials`.

Any help/solution is much appreciated.

Comment: [`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) takes both `--context` (if both clusters are defined in the same `.kube/config` file) and `--kubeconfig` options (if they're in separate files).

Comment: I'll try with the `--kubeconfig` flag, but the docs state that ["Only one instance of this flag is allowed"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/).

Comment: This documentation was recently updated , it may be of help, do keep in mind that you will have to use kubectl config set-credentials in the [configuration file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Answer (score 1):

If I need to work with multiple clusters using `kubectl` I am splitting my terminal and setting `KUBECONFIG` for each split:
For my first split:

```sh
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/cluster1
```

For the second split

```sh
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/cluster2
```

It is working pretty well, but this approach has one issue:
If you are using some kind of prompt with the current Kubernetes context it will give you different output and it might be missing leading.

For scripts, I am just changing value of `KUBECONFIG` in for loop, to loop over each cluster.

Comment: I might be able to run the script in a separate environment for each instance and set `KUBECONFIG` locally, hopefully that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Kubefed](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed) in order to manage multiple clusters.

It will take one cluster as the main one, and execute all the same requests to the second cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I'm interested in running different commands on the clusters.